# how to create a new workbook of excel with python getin data from other workbook

Tags: python, excel

how to create a new  workbook of excel with python getin  data from other workbook with python?
 I need automatically create a table, taking data from 5 other tables in a specific order know some method to this?

thanks for your answers!!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of the [xlrd and xlwt modules](http://www.python-excel.org/).  Perhaps, the xlutils [copy](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlutils/trunk/xlutils/docs/copy.txt) method can be of help.